# Selenium Hub Node with Docker containers on different hosts

Tags: selenium, docker, amazon-ec2, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I am trying to run docker Selenium on diff hosts

using these commands 
on Hub

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name hub selenium-hub:1.0.0
```

Node

```
docker run -d -p 5556:5556 -e REMOTE_HOST="http://nodeip:5556" -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hubip -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444 --name chrome-node3 selenium-chrome-node:1.0.0
```

How ever,I see the that the node is registered , but when i fire a test the request says pending

Here are the Hub logs

```
 14:50:29.078 WARN - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://10.205.87.185:5557
14:50:29.107 INFO - Registered a node http://10.205.87.185:5557
14:50:29.473 INFO - Marking the node http://10.205.87.185:5556 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
14:50:39.121 INFO - Marking the node http://10.205.87.185:5557 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
14:50:59.489 INFO - Unregistering the node http://10.205.87.185:5556 because it's been down for 30016 milliseconds
14:50:59.489 WARN - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://10.205.87.185:5556
14:50:59.516 INFO - Registered a node http://10.205.87.185:5556
14:51:09.192 INFO - Unregistering the node http://10.205.87.185:5557 because it's been down for 30071 milliseconds
14:51:09.192 WARN - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://10.205.87.185:5557
14:51:09.541 INFO - Marking the node http://10.205.87.185:5556 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
```

The Node seems to be up and running. Not sure what can be the issue

Comment: I see this error when i look at the console of Hub 
         
DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 10.205.87.185:5559 [/10.205.87.185] failed: Connection refused

Comment: Hello, what ip are you putting here? REMOTE_HOST="http://nodeip:5556"